# what is Mahaggataṃ citam? is it related to out of body experience?

Tags: pali-canon, sutras, terminology

the typical  translation of  Mahaggataṃ citam is , exalted , or expanded mind?

and in MN 127...two types of cetovimutti described.

(1)mahaggatā cetovimutti (expanded freedom of mind)

it related to  area..
area of size, 1 treeor 2 or 3 tree or village, or kingdom , or earth and so on..

(2) appamāṇā cetovimutti?  (limitless freedom of mind)

```
it described by direction.
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answer to this question is plainly self-evident in MN 127 cited in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Mahaggataṁ cetovimuttiṁ is the liberation of mind via loving-kindness. It is not an out-of-body experience.

> The limitless (appamāṇā) release of the heart and the expansive (mahaggatā) release of the heart mean the same thing, and differ only in the phrasing.”
>
> And what is the limitless release of the heart? It’s when a mendicant meditates spreading a heart full of love to one direction, and to the second, and to the third, and to the fourth. In the same way above, below, across, everywhere, all around, they spread a heart full of love to the whole world—abundant, expansive, limitless, free of enmity and ill will. They meditate spreading a heart full of compassion … They meditate spreading a heart full of rejoicing … They meditate spreading a heart full of equanimity to one direction, and to the second, and to the third, and to the fourth. In the same way above, below, across, everywhere, all around, they spread a heart full of equanimity to the whole world—abundant, expansive, limitless, free of enmity and ill will. This is called the limitless release of the heart.
>
> And what is the expansive release of the heart? It’s when a mendicant meditates determined on pervading the extent of a single tree root as expansive. This is called the expansive release of the heart. Also, a mendicant meditates determined on pervading the extent of two or three tree roots … a single village district … two or three village districts … a single kingdom … two or three kingdoms … this land surrounded by ocean. This too is called the expansive release of the heart. This is a way to understand how these things differ in both meaning and phrasing.
>
> [MN 127](https://suttacentral.net/mn127/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=plain&reference=none&notes=none&highlight=false&script=latin)

Comment: Just putting quotes from tipitak can not be said as answer. that we all know.

Answer (score 0):

The subject of meditation is different. In limitless meditation of heart we meditate on the directions North , South , East , West , up , down , left , right.
But in expansive meditation we meditate area wise , root of tree, villages , cities , kingdoms , nations , continents.

It is not necessarily out of body experience. To feel it ,you will have to give up jealousy, enmity, lust , aversion , delusion, ill will . Have a heart full of love , joy , compassion and equanimity. Not all at the same time but one by one. Unless you renounce the world it is difficult to experience or develop heart with aforementioned qualities. Renouncing the world is not easy in this materialistic world , however you can try by meditating at least for some time in solitude.